# html audio not working on macbook and ios, but works on imac -- weird

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, html5-audio

Working on this site: http://dev.bobpassaro.com/david/

There is some html audio (using mp3s) and js for the contoller buttons -- see the footer. On my iMac (running 10.8.5) it works fine. On my Macbook (10.9.4) it does not work. I'm running the identical version of Chrome on both. Getting the same behavior in Safari and Firefox, too.

But here's the really weird thing: if you go to the Albums page, then go to one of the albums (Cornish Sea, for instance) -- there are short samples of tunes-- also mp3s. These play as expected on both machines. The footer and the album pages use different templates but the underlying js that controls the audio is the same code.

My iphone also plays the samples on the album page, but not the full songs in the footer. The full songs are much bigger files, but I don't think that's it.

Any idea what might be happening here? I feel like I'm missing something simple -- or maybe not.

Comment: Can you post the relevant codes? You should have fallback formats.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of adding .ogg -- in researching <audio> it looked like .mp3 and .ogg would cover most browsers that are able to handle audio in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The path to your audio files is pointing at your localhost, which I assume is your iMac. You need to have the files hosted on a server, and change the source to path to that location. Where you have

```
<source src="http://localhost/david/wp-content/uploads/audio/cornish.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

you instead want that src value to be the server file path.

Comment: Doh! See. "missing something simple." Sorry to have to call in the troops for that one, but sometimes, it's good to have a fresh set of eyes. But that reminds me I should make the link dynamic. Thanks